# Ec2 Instance conection with RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I want to test if my ec2 instance that is in us-east-1 can connect to my database which is in us-west-2 same account.

I ssh into my instance ran the command:

```
echo '\dS' |psql -h rds-endpoint-xxx.amazonaws.com 5432
```

- the result I get is this:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "rds-endpoint-xxx.amazonaws.com" (192.168.12.233) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What does this mean? and what should i do to fix?

- My ec2 instance IP is 192.168.0.138 and in the security group of my rds database I have allowed inbound access from it.

[image]

- I also have created a vpc peering connection between both vpc of the instance and the rds database.
- Why do I still get the error?

Comment: Do you have the "Publicly Accessible" property turned on?

Comment: A few tests you can try: #1: If you were to launch another EC2 instance in the **same VPC as the Amazon RDS instance**, and login, are you able to connect to the database? (Testing Security Group) #2: Can you connect from the EC2 instance in us-east to this new instance in us-west? (Testing VPC Peering)

Comment: @jellycsc I cannot have it as public.. thats why I made the vpc peering connection so it can work but its not..